# Running an ActiveX DLL in firefox

Tags: delphi, firefox, dll, activex

Hello Guys:
I have written an activeX dll in Delphi and I want to run in in firefox. How can I do that?

Is there anyway that I can make an .xpt directly form this dll or not?

Comment: ActiveX hosted inside a browser is a dying technology. In truth it has been dying for many years. With browsers other than IE becoming so widespread you will find much resistance from users. Many environments will block ActiveX in the browser even in IE for security reasons. I know this doesn't help you today, but it's worth knowing all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to just make an .xpi directly from the DLL. An ActiveX control needs an ActiveX host which Firefox is not, by default. It seems it can be, however, with an installed plugin.
A quick Google search for "firefox activex" reveals:

- [ff-activex-host](http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/)
- [Neptune](http://www.meadroid.com/neptune/index.htm)
- [Mozilla ActiveX Project](http://www.adamlock.com/mozilla/) (seems abandoned but there's reference and source code for Firefox 1.x)